# Type not inherited in SFINAE for multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++, templates, multiple-inheritance, type-inference, sfinae

I am using a [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFINAE) mechanism to deduce a type. `Resolve<T>::type` is deduced to `T` if `class T` doesn't contain `yes` and it's deduced to `MyClass` if it contains `yes`.

```
class MyClass {};

template<typename>
struct void_ { typedef void check; };

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct Resolve { typedef T type; };

template<typename T>
struct Resolve <T, typename void_<typename T::yes>::check> {
    typedef MyClass type;
};
```

Now, I have the simple test classes as,

```
struct B1 { typedef int yes; }; // 1
struct B2 { typedef int yes; }; // 2
struct D1 {};  // 3
struct D2 : B1 {};  // 4
struct D3 : B1, B2 {}; // 5 <----
```

According to the logic following should be the result for above tests:

1. `Resove<B1>::type = MyClass`
2. `Resove<B2>::type = MyClass`
3. `Resove<D1>::type = D1`
4. `Resove<D2>::type = MyClass`
5. `Resove<D3>::type = MyClass` or **compiler error** (due to ambiguity between B1, B2)

Strangely, in test case (5) it doesn't happen so. The result is,

```
Resolve<D3>::type = D3;
```

Can anyone explain, what *magic* is happening specially for multiple inheritance ? Not getting compiler error is a standard compliant behavior ? Here is the [demo](http://ideone.com/xAzHV).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you expect a compiler error? You know *SFINAE* stands for `Substitution Failure Is Not An Error` right?

When you substitute `T` by `D3` the expression becames ambiguous. Due to SFINAE, this failure is not considered an error and your specialization is simply removed as a candidate. It's all about *NOT* getting a compiler error.

Comment: Correct. But in this case, there are 2 `typedef`s are coming to `D3`, through `B1` and `B2`; that's why I was expecting an error. If not error, the `type` should be `Myclass` as in case of `D2`.

Comment: -1: This is a bad answer. First, it does not relate to the specific problem in the question. Second, it uses a very strange logic - SFINAE just means that there will not be an error as long as at least one suitable substitution can be found, and there is no ambiguity.

Comment: @Bjorn: How does it not relate? In the OP case there is no error because the specialization results in failure and the default template is a suitable substitution, and is the only one in the set so there is no ambiguity.

Comment: What my confusion is that, why shouldn't there be any ambiguity ? There are 2 `typedef`s involved in `D3`. 1st is coming through `B1` and 2nd one through `B2`. How come both are discarded. You can just try removing either of the `typedef`s and then `Resove<D3>::type = MyClass` will be the result.

Comment: @iammilind: There **is** an ambiguity, that ambiguity is what makes that particular substitution result in a failure and that's when SFINAE kicks off and prevents that error by discarding your specialization from the viable candidates. As a result, you are left with only one candidate that provides a viable substitution -the default one-, and is the one that is picked.