# SFINAE tried with bool gives compiler error: "template argument ‘T::value’ involves template parameter"

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, sfinae

I tried to implement an SFINAE using `bool` (unlike popular `void_` [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709703/type-not-inherited-in-sfinae-for-multiple-inheritance)):

```
  template<typename T, bool = true>
  struct Resolve
  {
    static const bool value = false;
  };

  template<typename T>
  struct Resolve<T, T::my_value>
  {
    static const bool value = true;
  };
```

The goal is to specialize, the classes which have `static const bool my_value = true;` defined inside it. If they are defined `false` or not defined then don't specialize it. i.e.

```
struct B1 {  // specialize Resolve for this case
  static const bool my_value = true;
};
struct B2 {  // don't specialize
  static const bool my_value = false;
};
struct B3 {};  // don't specialize
```

When applying the above trick on `B1` it gives the compilation error:

```
Resolve<B1>::value;
```

> error: template argument ‘T::my_value’ involves template parameter(s)

I am aware that this can be achieved with alternate ways. However, I am interested in knowing, why it gives compiler error here and can it be solved in this code itself ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Actually what you're doing is forbidden by section §14.5.4/9 which says,

> A partially specialized **non-type argument expression shall not involve a template parameter of the partial specialization** except when the argument expression is a simple identifier.

The trick could be using a *type* for second template parameter as well, encapsulating the *non-type* value, as described below:

```
template<bool b> struct booltype {};

template<typename T, typename B = booltype<true> >
struct Resolve
{
  static const bool value = false;
};

template<typename T>
struct Resolve<T, booltype<T::my_value> >
{
  static const bool value = true;
};
```

Now it [compile fines](http://ideone.com/4r6My).

Comment: Nice solution. I have edited some part and the example. For my specific requirement I wanted to explore `bool` trick rather than `void_` trick for SFINAE. Also, if it's forbidden by standard then, I think I should accept this answer, because I don't see any other way out.

Comment: Well, the edit is okay. I thought you could use the member in `bool2type`, that is why I added it. But if you don't need it, then it is perfectly fine with me.

Comment: Ahh, this is exactly the solution I needed for my problem.  [Question 15115109](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115109/how-to-convert-templated-function-overloads-to-partial-specialized-templated-cla)  I took it a step further by using std::integral_constant< typename bool, bool b >, and those that are directly available via type_traits' "::type" member.

Comment: I adapted the same solution to my own application. I deal with templates that take function pointers as non-type template parameters. In the context of the question here, the workaround is `template<auto> struct value_to_type {}; template<typename... T> struct Resolve<value_to_type<my_function<T...>>> {...};`

Comment: Nowadays you can use `std::bool_constant` from `<type_traits>` instead own `booltype`