# Is sizeof... allowed in template arguments for specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sizeof, template-specialization

I'm trying to do something along the lines of this using GCC 4.7 snapshot:

```
template <int n, int... xs>
struct foo { 
  static const int value = 0;
};

// partial specialization where n is number of ints in xs:

template <int... xs>
struct foo<sizeof...(xs), xs...> { // error: template argument ‘sizeof (xs ...)’
                                   //  involves template parameter(s)
  static const int value = 1;
};

template <int... xs>
struct foo<sizeof(xs), xs...> { // This compiles fine. sizeof(xs) is sizeof int 
                                // even though packs aren't expanded
  static const int value = 2;
};
```

The error is strange because sizeof instead of sizeof... works in this case. Both seem like they could be easily computed during compile time.

**Is the compiler correct that I can't use `sizeof...` in template arguments for specialization?**

Comment: You mean `sizeof(xs)` works? I would expect a complaint about not-expanded packs.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Strangely it does work.

Comment: Same error, simpler code: http://ideone.com/BBKbw. The second may be an error in the compiler, or just that `sizeof(xs) == sizeof(int)` and hence does not involve the template arguments. - As a practical solution: `value = sizeof...(xs) == n;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume this is a compiler issue after reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776448/sfinae-tried-with-bool-gives-compiler-error-template-argument-tvalue-invol).

> A partially specialized non-type argument expression shall not involve a template parameter of the partial specialization except when the argument expression is a simple identifier.

Which is being disputed [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1315).

GCC is either incorrectly unpacking  the parameter pack, or evaluating `sizeof` prematurely.

[Response to bug report I filed may be helpful.](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51155#c1)