# sizeof<integral type> not accepted as integral template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

The compiler (GCC 4.7.2) seems to have a problem with this code:

```
  template<int BoolSize> struct BoolReg {};
  template<> struct BoolReg<1> { static const Jit::RegType Val_t = Jit::u8; };
  template<> struct BoolReg<2> { static const Jit::RegType Val_t = Jit::u16; };
  template<> struct BoolReg<4> { static const Jit::RegType Val_t = Jit::u32; };

  template <class T> struct JitRegType {};

  template <> struct JitRegType<bool>   { static const Jit::RegType Val_t = BoolReg< sizeof<bool> >::Val_t; };
```

It says:

> error: template argument 1 is invalid

at the last line of the code above. Whereas when passing an integer literal instead of `sizeof(bool)` it works fine:

```
  template <> struct JitRegType<bool>   { static const Jit::RegType Val_t = BoolReg<1>::Val_t; };
```

However, the size of a `bool` is not specified by the standard thus I'd like to use the more portable way and specify the register type according to the size of the `bool`.

Is this really ill-formed C++11 ?

The standard says:

> A template-argument for a non-type, non-template template-parameter
>   shall be one of:
>
> an integral constant-expression of integral or enumeration type; or
>   the name of a non-type template-parameter; or the address of an object
>   or function with external linkage, including function templates and
>   function template-ids but excluding non-static class members,
>   expressed as & id-expression where the & is optional if the name
>   refers to a function or array, or if the corresponding
>   template-parameter is a reference; or a pointer to member expressed as
>   described in 5.3.1 .

Comment: This is not a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147010/is-sizeof-allowed-in-template-arguments-for-specialization because there its partial specialization. That's not what I am doing here

Comment: Argh!!! Its too early in the morning! Thanks for this!

Comment: The title was better! Changed the title ;-)

Comment: If `BoolSize` is really a size, then I'd suggest that you should use a `size_t` template parameter rather than an `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `sizeof(bool)` rather than `sizeof<bool>`. That is `sizeof` isn't a template.

Comment: Yeah! Stupid things happen before the first coffee ;-)