# Size of parameter pack in template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, circular-dependency

I have a template that provides a type for any given Order in the range from `0` to `MaxOrder`.

```
template <class Graph, int Order> TypeHelper;
```

This is necessary because `TypeHelper<Graph, k>` depends on `TypeHelper<Graph, 0>`, `TypeHelper<Graph, k - 1>` and `TypeHelper<Graph, k + 1>`.

`Graph` is a variadic template that serves as a container for the type of the `Payload` for any given order.

```
template <class... Payloads> Graph;
```

In order to terminate the recursion at `TypeHelper<Graph, 0>` and `TypeHelper<Graph, MaxOrder>` these are specialized. The former is straight forward but I cannot figure out how to derive `MaxOrder` from the number of types in `Payloads...`.
One obvious solution is to introduce `MaxOrder` as a template parameter of `Graph`.
As an example:

```
template <int MaxOrder, class... Payloads> Graph;

template <template <int, class...> class Graph, int MaxOrder, class... Payloads>
struct TypeHelper<Graph<MaxOrder, Payloads...>, MaxOrder>
```

But I would prefer something like this

```
template <template <class...> class Graph, class... Payloads>
struct TypeHelper<Graph<Payloads...>, sizeof...(Payloads)>
```

But this does not work.

Further reading: [Is sizeof... allowed in template arguments for specialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147010/is-sizeof-allowed-in-template-arguments-for-specialization)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to deduce `Graph` as template template parameter, or should it be the `Graph` you defined before?

Comment: Graph is defined first and thereby every payload type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I got the problem, but you can still use an intermediate class that inherits from your actual implementation:

```
template <class Graph, int Order>
struct TypeHelperImpl;

// specializations of TypeHelperImpl

template <typename...>
struct TypeHelper;

template <template <class...> class Graph, class... Payloads>
struct TypeHelper<Graph<Payloads...>, Payloads...>
    : TypeHelperImpl<Graph<Payloads...>, sizeof...(Payloads)> {};
```

Comment: This would always create the `TypeHelper<Graph, MaxOrder>`, but this points in the right direction. The Order of your solution is MaxOrder. Adding another parameter Order to all classes solves the problem.