# How To Convert Templated Function Overloads to Partial-Specialized Templated Class Static Methods?

Tags: c++, templates, static-methods, sfinae, partial-specialization

I have several functions that I want to specialize based on type qualities, such as "character, signed-integer, unsigned-integer, floating-point, pointer"; using type_traits seems like *the* way to do this, and have code similar to the to the following:

```
#include <tr1/type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<bool, typename _Tp = void>
struct enable_if 
{ };

template<typename _Tp>
struct enable_if<true, _Tp>
{
    typedef _Tp type;
};


template< typename T >
inline void
foo_impl( typename enable_if< std::tr1::is_integral< T >::value, T >::type const& )
{
    std::cout << "This is the function-overloaded integral implementation.\n";
}

template< typename T >
inline void
foo_impl( typename enable_if< std::tr1::is_floating_point< T >::value, T >::type const& )
{
    std::cout << "This is the function-overloaded floating-point implementation.\n";
}

template< typename T >
inline void
function_overloads_foo( T const& arg )
{
    foo_impl< T >( arg ); // vital to specify the template-type
}

void function_overloads_example()
{
    function_overloads_foo( int() );
    function_overloads_foo( float() );
}
```

except in my real code, I also have `bar`,`baz`, etc., along with `foo`.

However, I would like to group all of these functions per quality into one templated class as `static` methods.  How is this best done?  Here's my naive, and broken attempt to use Tags, SFINAE, and partial-specialization:

```
struct IntegralTypeTag;
struct FloatingPointTypeTag;

template< typename T, typename U = void >
class Foo
{
};

template< typename T >
class Foo< T, typename enable_if< std::tr1::is_integral< T >::value, IntegralTypeTag >::type >
{
    static void foo( T const& )
    {
        std::cout << "This is the integral partial-specialization class implementation.\n";
    }
};

template< typename T >
class Foo< T, typename enable_if< std::tr1::is_floating_point< T >::value, FloatingPointTypeTag >::type >
{
    static void foo( T const& )
    {
        std::cout << "This is the floating-point partial-specialization class implementation.\n";
    }
};

template< typename T >
inline void
partial_specialization_class_foo( T const& arg )
{
    Foo< T >::foo( arg );
}

void partial_specialization_class_example()
{
    partial_specialization_class_foo( int() );
    partial_specialization_class_foo( float() );
}
```

*Note*: in my real code, I'd have `bar`,`baz`, etc., along with `foo` static-methods.

FYI, this is C++03.

As an aside, am I doing the templated function overloading in the conventional way?

Comment: I don't understand why `function_overload_foo()` is "vital to specify the template-type". You're not doing anything there, just forwarding

Comment: Yes, I thought so too, but my compiler 'gcc-4.7' complains without it:

error: no matching function for call to ‘foo_impl(const int&)’
note: candidates are:
note: template<class T> void foo_impl(const typename enable_if<std::tr1::is_integral<_Tp>::value, T>::type&)
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’
note: template<class T> void foo_impl(const typename enable_if<std::tr1::is_floating_point<T>::value, T>::type&)
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’

Comment: @AndyProwl: If you don't mention the template argument, the compiler cannot deduce it from the function argument, because it is non-deducible context. [See this to know why it is non-deducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060824/c-template-argument-can-not-be-deduced)

Comment: @Nawaz: Of course. I just had read the whole thing too superficially. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
#include <tr1/type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct IntegralTypeTag;
struct FloatingPointTypeTag;

template <
  typename T,
  bool is_integral = std::tr1::is_integral<T>::value,
  bool is_floating_point = std::tr1::is_floating_point<T>::value
> struct TypeTag;

template <typename T>
struct TypeTag<T,true,false> {
  typedef IntegralTypeTag Type;
};

template <typename T>
struct TypeTag<T,false,true> {
  typedef FloatingPointTypeTag Type;
};

template <typename T,typename TypeTag = typename TypeTag<T>::Type> struct Foo;


template <typename T>
struct Foo<T,IntegralTypeTag> {
  static void foo( T const& )
  {
    std::cout << "This is the integral partial-specialization class implementation.\n";
  }
};

template <typename T>
struct Foo<T,FloatingPointTypeTag> {
  static void foo( T const& )
  {
    std::cout << "This is the floating-point partial-specialization class implementation.\n";
  }
};

template< typename T >
inline void
partial_specialization_class_foo( T const& arg )
{
      Foo< T >::foo( arg );
}

int main(int,char**)
{
  partial_specialization_class_foo(int());
  partial_specialization_class_foo(float());
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer works, uses Tags like I was trying, and sequesters all the type_traits checking to the one `TypeTag`.

However, the whole structure seems more complicated than necessary to me, so after reading the answers here, I was able to refine my original approach to not rely on Tags at all.  I posted the code and explanation as a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

After observing Vaughn's correct answer, I wanted to simplify it more.  I was able to remove the use of Tags and extra trait-classes to come up with the following structure:

```
template< typename T, typename U = T >
struct Foo
{
};

template< typename T >
struct Foo< T, typename enable_if< std::tr1::is_integral< T >::value, T >::type >
{
    static void foo( T const& )
    {
        std::cout << "This is the integral partial-specialization class implementation.\n";
    }
};

template< typename T >
struct Foo< T, typename enable_if< std::tr1::is_floating_point< T >::value, T >::type >
{
    static void foo( T const& )
    {
        std::cout << "This is the floating-point partial-specialization class implementation.\n";
    }
};

template< typename T >
inline void
partial_specialization_class_foo( T const& arg )
{
    Foo< T >::foo( arg );
}

void partial_specialization_class_example()
{
    partial_specialization_class_foo( int() );
    partial_specialization_class_foo( float() );
}
```

I think this works by providing two template-type parameters to the class, where the second one is compile-time conditional:

- This defaults to being same as the first parameter, so the caller only focuses on the first parameter.
- Only partial-specializations that have the same second template param as the first can be matched.
- When `enable_if` fails, the whole partial-specialization is unavailable to match against.

I find it less cumbersome to understand, comparatively.

Comment: Turns out, I was able to refine my answer even more, after reading [Question 7776448](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776448/sfinae-tried-with-bool-gives-compiler-error-template-argument-tvalue-invol)  I took it a step further by using std::integral_constant< typename bool, bool b >, and those that are directly available via type_traits' "::type" member.

Answer (score 0):

`IntegralTypeTag` in the `enable_if` will get in the way.  The default for the second parameter of `Foo` is `void`, which is not the same as `IntegralTypeTag`, so the specialization of `Foo` will fail to match.

Ie, `Foo< int, void >` (which is what you get when you do `Foo<int>`) does not match `Foo< int, IntegralTypeTag >`, which your intended `int` specialization is (after the `enable_if` logic).

Tagging is the result of a `type_traits` class, which you can then use to simplify other `type_traits` classes.