# How to write out contents of a tuple in C++11 using recursive class templates?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl, tuples

I tried the following recursion to write out the elements of a `tuple`, but I have trouble in the line that computes the `tuple` size at compile time (commented out below):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Tuple, std::size_t element = 0>
struct write_tuple
{
    static void execute(Tuple const & t)
    {
        std::cout << std::get<element>(t) << std::endl; 
        write_tuple<Tuple, element + 1>::execute(t); 
    }
};

template<typename Tuple>
struct write_tuple<Tuple, 4>  // This works fine
//struct write_tuple<Tuple, std::tuple_size<typename Tuple>::value >  // std::tuple_size should give me the size of the tuple at compile-time
{
    static void execute(Tuple const & t) {}; 
};

template<typename Tuple>
void write(Tuple const & t)
{
    write_tuple<Tuple>::execute(t); 
}

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    tuple<string, int, double, string> myTuple = std::make_tuple("test", 0, 2.1, "finished"); 

    write(myTuple);

    return 0;
}
```

The line:

```
struct write_tuple<Tuple, 4>
```

works perfectly fine to terminate the recursive call for a `tuple` of size 4, but when I use the `std::tuple_size<typename Tuple>::value` to get the `tuple` size at compile time, I get the following error:

```
main.cpp:17:57: error: template argument 1 is invalid
     struct write_tuple<Tuple, std::tuple_size<typename Tuple>::value >  // std::tuple_size should give me the size of the tuple at compile-time
                                                             ^
main.cpp:17:66: error: template argument 2 is invalid
     struct write_tuple<Tuple, std::tuple_size<typename Tuple>::value >  // std::tuple_size should give me the size of the tuple at compile-time
```

I am using gcc 4.8.2.

Edit:

removing the `typename` from `std::tuple_size<typename Tuple>::value` results with the following error:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main  2>&1 | tee log 
main.cpp:17:8: error: template argument ‘std::tuple_size<_Tp>::value’ involves template parameter(s)
 struct write_tuple<Tuple, std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>  // std::tuple_size should give me the size of the tuple at compile-time
```

Comment: change std::tuple_size<typename Tuple>::value to simply std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value. The typename keyword is invalid in that context.

Comment: @user1353535: thanks, I tried it already, see the edited question.

Comment: It is unable to infer the specialization. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776448/sfinae-tried-with-bool-gives-compiler-error-template-argument-tvalue-invol

A better way would be to count down from tuple_size to 0 instead of counting up from 0 to tuple_size;

Comment: @user1353535: thanks for the other question, I'm reading it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your code, you may reverse the recursion, like:

```
template<typename Tuple, std::size_t remaining>
struct write_tuple
{
    static void execute(Tuple const & t)
    {
        std::cout << std::get<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value - remaining>(t) << std::endl;
        write_tuple<Tuple, remaining - 1>::execute(t);
    }
};

template<typename Tuple>
struct write_tuple<Tuple, 0>
{
    static void execute(Tuple const & t) {};
};

template<typename Tuple>
void write(Tuple const & t)
{
    write_tuple<Tuple, std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>::execute(t);
}
```

An alternative approach:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

#if 1 // Not in C++11

template <std::size_t ...> struct index_sequence {};

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ...Is>
struct make_index_sequence : make_index_sequence<N - 1, N - 1, Is...> {};

template <std::size_t ... Is>
struct make_index_sequence<0, Is...> : index_sequence<Is...> {};

#endif // make_index_sequence

template<typename Tuple>
struct write_tuple
{
    static void execute(Tuple const & t)
    {
        execute(t, make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>());
    }

private:
    template<std::size_t ... Is>
    static void execute(Tuple const & t, index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        const int dummy[] = {0, (write_element(std::get<Is>(t)), 0)...};
        static_cast<void>(dummy); // silent warning for unused variable.
    }

    template <typename T>
    static void write_element(T const &elem)
    {
        std::cout << elem << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a quirk of the language: non-type parameter values cannot be dependent on type parameter values in a specialization.  Probably the standardization comittee had a reason.  It may have been a good one.

There are a few ways to solve your problem, the easiest beimg to recurse down to `0` and print on the way back up the recursion.  One that involves the least change to your code would be to add a `, typename=void>` parameter to your `class template`, and in the specialization add the size in, then `, size, typename std::enable_if<size==std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>::type>` added to the end of the specialization.  This makes the test in a type parameter, specialized on `void` (which is always there), but only valid when SFINAE succeeds and the size matches the tuple size.