# Meta-programming calculations with parametrized type -> "template argument X involves template parameter(s)"

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I have simple template metaprogramming class to calculate the bits set of a number:

```
template <int x>
struct BitsSet {
    static const int n = BitsSet<(x >> 1)>::n + (x & 1);
};
template <>
struct BitsSet<0> {
    static const int n = 0u;
};
```

Which works fine, but I'd like the template to be more flexible on the type holding the number, for example:

```
template <typename T, T x>
struct BitsSet {
    static const T n = BitsSet<T, (x >> 1)>::n + (x & 1);
};
template <typename T>
struct BitsSet<T, 0> {
    static const int n = 0u;
};
```

However the error is:

```
significant.h:32:12: error: template argument ‘(T)0’ involves template parameter(s)
    32 |     struct BitsSet<T, 0> {
```

I belive that it fails given the point [(5) of the description for partial specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) Am  I right?

As well there are several questions relating to this error, I think [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7776468/3794981) being the closest... but honestly I am not capable to reach a solution to my problem.

A simplier question would be: how do you parametrize the *int* type in the typical *factorial template calculation*?

Comment: For reference, this is often referred to as the "pop count" or Hamming weight of an integer, and is already available as [`std::popcount`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount)

Comment: Relevant: [Are the results of bitwise operations on signed integers defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11644362/11082165)

Comment: `std::popcount` is a [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) function, which can be evaluated in constant expressions (i.e., at compile time). See [When does a constexpr function get evaluated at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14248235/11082165)